# Calculating theoretical FPS

Tags: hardware, requirements

*I'm unsure if this question would be more appropriate in stackoverflow, so apologies before hand if it should be moved.*

Given that I know the user's hardware (Video Card, RAM, CPU, screen resolution, etc.) is it possible to make a rough estimate of the expected FPS when comparing with the game's minimum and recommended system requirements?

I see some gaming websites with those estimates and I was wondering how do they do it.

Comment: The way gaming website have those numbers is that they have computers with that hardware and they installed and tested the game on them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about game development.

Comment: By the way, the "minimum" and "recommended" system requirements of games are usually just a guess by the developers. There is no standardized process behind coming up with these specs. The only thing that really matters is that the game does at least run on the hardware specified in the "minimum requirements", or you might get into trouble for false advertisement.

Comment: @ratchetfreak for the sake of giving this question a conclusion that can be Accepted, I think it would be worth posting that comment as an answer. In general I think it's valid to answer "How do I...?" questions with "You can't, because..." when applicable.

Answer (score 1):

As *ratchet freak* said, the estimates are based on running the game on a set of different hardware configurations. Often, they will load a set of different game configurations on those computer systems as well. That way they can gather information such as "Game ABC runs at **72.4 fps** on a system with **CPU XXX**, **GPU YYY**, with **ZZZ GB of RAM**, on **Ultra High settings**."

Not all pieces of a **hardware configuration** contribute equally to the framerate of a game. Often, the GPU is the most important factor, followed by the CPU, the amount of RAM, and whether an SSD is used or a standard HDD.

In terms of **game configurations**, two important factors are graphical fidelity (i.e. low quality graphics all the way to ultra high quality graphics) and display resolution (i.e. how many screens are you rendering to, and what resolution do they run at).

By obtaining a set of benchmarks on various systems, and in various game configurations, you can often extrapolate your data to different hardware configurations to make an estimation of the framerate on unmeasured systems. You could simply use the benchmark that is the most similar to the user's configuration (looking at the most important hardware components), or you could calculate a weighted average across multiple benchmarks based on similarity.